# If H and K are subgroups of a group G and HK equals G, must H or K be normal in G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Another question: If H and K are subgroups of G, can we say that HK is a subgroup of G if and only if H is in the normalizer of K or K is in the normalizer of H? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. There's a well-known theorem that $KH=HK$ iff $HK$ is a subgroup, and you can derive your statement from this.

Answer (score 2):

In general if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, we have $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $HK=KH$.

---

The first statement is false

The alternating group $A_5$ is a simple group, so it has no proper normal subgroups.

Taking the subgroups $H=\langle(1,2,3,4,5)\rangle$ and $K=\langle (1,2)(3,4),(1,2,3)\rangle$ yields a counter-example (Notice $K$ is a copy of $A_4$ inside $A_5$)

To verify use $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$ and notice $H$ has order $5$ and $K$ order $12$

The second statement is also false, the same counterexample works:

$(123)(12345)(321)=(14523)$ which is not in $\langle (12345)\rangle$

$(12345)(234)(54321)=(345)$ which is not in $\langle (12)(34),(123) \rangle$

Comment: A4 is not simple, and the K you give is a normal subgroup.

Comment: Oh right, don't worry, I'll fix it right away

Comment: It is fixed now.