# Is there a more general group product than the semidirect product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group with $G=HK$ and $H\cap K=\emptyset$. If both $H$ and $K$ are normal in $G$, then $G=H\times K$. We can use this as inspiration to define the (external) direct product of any two groups.

Now, if $H$ is normal in $G$ but not $K$, then $G$ is a semidirect product of $H$ and $K$, $G=H\rtimes K$. We can again use this as inspiration to define an external semidirect product of any two groups, although this product won't be unique for the two groups (we have to specify a map from one to the automorphism group of the other).

But what if neither $H$ nor $K$ is normal in $G$? We can see that this is possible, e.g. in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1256978/if-h-and-k-are-subgroups-of-a-group-g-and-hk-equals-g-must-h-or-k-be-normal-in). Does this give rise to a more general external product of two groups than the semidirect product?

Comment: The term you want is "Zappa-Szep product."

Comment: You may be interested in reading up on the "extension problem" and "wreath product".